# Download swf files from a flash site embedded with SWFObject?

Tags: flash

We need to download swf files from a Moto CMS and we don't have access through FTP.  The swfs are embedded with object tags.  Is there a way to get the data from an object without an FTP connection?

Answer (score 1):

Look through the website source code for the actual address of the SWF file and go to that link with any browser or download manager and you should be able to get the file. Otherwise you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but was only able to download a PEG file and it's way too small to contain an SWF.  Are PEGs compatible with Flash Pro?

Comment: @dcd018 so far as I know a peg is a game data file!

Comment: Well it is 100% flash site which is why we need the swfs, so I can convert them to HTML5/JS.  Maybe it's a shockwave file?  IDK, either way thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @dcd018 can you give me the url?

Answer (score 0):

WM Recorder is a great program to capture flash videos streaming it'll save them to your local drive as they play http://wmrecorder.com/products

Answer (score 0):

You may try **[Internet Download Manager](http://internetdownloadmanager.com)**.